# Publish on Project using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, publish, ms-project

I need to publish Project plans from a list.

All the code is done and running.

```
.Publish Republish:=Null, WssUrl:=Null

'Store timer
dblTimer = Timer
'Pause 5 seconds to allow publish window to appear
Do While dblTimer + 30 > Timer

     DoEvents

Loop
'Enable publish
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

The publish window pops on Project. The VBA stops until I click on publish in the window, which has to be done with the SendKeys.

Is there a way to publish without popping the window, or making VBA run when the window pops?

Comment: `oProject.DisplayAlerts=False` ?

Comment: I already use it and it doesnt work with this window as its not an alert window

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a line and use the FileSave method first then publish the project plan `enter`i.e. `enter`
Application.FileSave 
Application.Publishp True, Null

Comment: Can you be more specific?